# Passing JS functions to WASM

Tags: javascript, webassembly, emcc

I am reading a beautiful book about WebAssembly, and I am trying to learn how to import JS functions into `wasm` without using "glue code".

So [this is the C file](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Learn-WebAssembly/blob/master/chapter-05-create-load-module/without-glue.c) where 2 `extern` functions are declared

```c
extern int jsClearRect();
extern int jsFillRect();
```

I then compile the `c` code into `wasm` with the following instructions:

```
emcc src/main.c -Os -s STANDALONE_WASM=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1  -o main.wasm
```

and then I am instructed to write a JS script which `instantiate` the wasm file, defines `jsFillRect()` and `jsClearRect()` and import them into the module's `env` by using an import object.

```js
// define the import Objects
const importObj = {
    "env": {
        "__memory_base":0,
        "tableBase":0,
        "memory": new WebAssembly.Memory({ initial: 256 }),
        "table": new WebAssembly.Table({ initial: 8, element: 'anyfunc' }),
        jsClearRect(): function() {/*function definition here*/},
        jsFillRect(): function() {/*function definition here*/},
    }
}
// import the module
fetch('main.wasm')
        .then(obj => WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(obj,importObject))
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

and I get an Error:

```
TypeError: import object field 'GOT.mem' is not an Object
```

The import object that I am presenting here is already a modified version of the orginal one (that you can find [here](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Learn-WebAssembly/blob/master/chapter-05-create-load-module/without-glue.html)). In this example the functions are declared in JS as `_jsClearRect()` but the module could not find a definition of `jsClearRect()`. Then the it could not find a definition of `__memory_base` because it was declared as `memoryBase`but now I don't know what king of `Object` represent `GOT.mem`.

I have been looking around and my feeling is that I am using an old API, but I cannot find a proper solution to achieve this.

So my QUESTION is:

How do I import a Javascript functions into a wasm module?

Answer (score 0):

The `GOT.mem` come from the dynamic linking ABI used by emscripten.  In this case I don't think you want/need the dyanamic linking stuff and you can/should just remove `-sSIDE_MODULE`.

This should simplify/reduce the imports you need to provide.  (For example, you won't need to provide `table` or `memory`).

Comment: I tried that, but I have no `main` function in my Module. Building fails

Comment: You can use `--no-entry` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword "static" should be added for the declarations of variables *isRunning* and *rect* to make them only to be seen inside the C file, otherwise, Emscripten will treat them as WebAssembly.Global variable and ask for an input.

With *static* keyword, it compiled to:
[Compiled with static keyword](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwdNS.png)

Without *static* keyword:
[Compiled without static keyword](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcWUG.png)